# Simple Windows Phone application

Tags: windows-phone

I want to create a simple windows phone app that has a ball bouncing around. Is there any chance creating this app without using XNA?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can do it using XAML. Create a ball in canvas. Then change its position using `Canvas.Left`, and `Canvast.Top` properties. Create `DispatcherTimer` to have a *game loop*.

**MainPage.xaml**

```xml
<Canvas>
    <Ellipse x:Name="MyBall" 
             Width="64" 
             Height="64" 
             Fill="Red" />
</Canvas>
```

Change ball position with timer (code below).

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
// Your "game loop" timer
DispatcherTimer timer;

// Ball position
int x = 0; 
int y = 0;

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Tick += OnTimerTick;
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.Zero; // It's about 60 fps
    timer.Start();
}

// This is your "game loop", where you can change things, move, animate, etc.
private void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Change ball position
    x++;
    y++;

    // Apply new position
    Canvas.SetLeft(MyBall, x); // Set x
    Canvas.SetTop(MyBall, y); // Set y
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This will help me go deeper into what i want to do.

Answer (score 0):

you could use Physics Helper Xaml from Codeplex to do this:

https://physicshelperxaml.codeplex.com/

here is some older examples that does it in silverlight using an older version of the library might be useful:

http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Creating-a-Pinball-Game-in-Silverlight-Using-the-Physics-Helper-Library--Farseer-Physics